# How to convert embedded CRLF codes to their REAL newlines in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline

I searched everywhere for this, the problem is that the search criteria is very similar to other questions.
The issue I have is that file (script actually) is embedded in another file. So when I open the parent file I can see the script as massive string with several \n and \r\n codes. I need a way to convert these codes to what they should be so that it formats the code correctly then I can read said code and work on it.

Quick snippet:

```
\n\n\n\n\nlocal scriptingFunctions\n\n\n\n\nlocal measuringCircles = {}\r\nlocal isCurrentlyCheckingCoherency
```

Should covert to:

```
local scriptingFunctions



local measuringCircles = {}


local isCurrentlyCheckingCoherency
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perform a Regex Find-Replace

Find: `(\\r)?\\n`

Replace: `\n`

Comment: But the string doesn't have two slashes like \\* so how would that work? If it does, what are using to do it in? PowerShell, bash etc? I am on a windows machine

Comment: hmm, stackoverflow interecpted bt double backslash. I meanto say that the string does not have 2x backslashes then [n] like in your regex example so I don't think it would work

Comment: @Mucker you have to escape the backslash in a regex, I use VSC like you tagged the question, with single backslash would be converted to the ascii chars <32, and you have literal backslash-n in your code

Comment: Ah I see now, didn't know you could use regex in the find and replace box in vscode. This worked! Thank you all

Comment: This worked but it didn't get rid of them all. I can't figure out why. some of them start like so now \ntext or text\r\n\text. How to replace these?

Comment: Ah found it, it was a setting in Vscode itself to only match on words, turning it meant it captured them all. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to reconvert from newlines to `\n` after you're done working on the code, you can accomplish the trick by simply pressing `ctrl-f` and substituting every occurrence of `\n` with a new line (you can type enter in the replace box by pressing `ctrl-enter` or `shift-enter`).

See an example ctrl-f to do this:

[image: a ctrl-f setup]

---

If after you're done working on the code you need to reconvert to `\n`, you can add an invisible char to the replace string (typing it like `ctrl-enter` `invisibleChar`), and after you're done you can re-replace it with `\n`.
There's plenty of invisible chars, but I'd personally suggest `[U+200b]` (you can copy it from [here](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/200B)); another good one is `[U+2800]` (⠀), as it renders as a normal whitespace, and thus is noticeable.

A thing to notice is that recent versions of vscode will show a highlight around invisible chars, but you can easily disable it by clicking on `Adjust settings` and then selecting `Exclude from being highlighted`.
If you need to reenable highlighting in the future, you'll have to look for `"editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters"` in the settings.

Comment: This is on the right track and I tried something like this originally myself but didn't know about the ctrl+enter. I just tried it now but it's not allowing the \ when try it, it does allows just n by itself try itself yourself quickly and the find buttons grey out if you have \ there. Any thoughts?

Comment: It works just fine for me... Would you mind sending a pic of the grayed out find box?